# Text displays on top of popup menu

Tags: html, css, transparency

I made a simple HTML page with a simple drop-down menu (made with CSS). I have a problem with the drop-down text transparency: it shows the bottom text (as explained in the image below). The text in the menu is a link, so it's included in a  tag. I tried to change the text color and opacity property but doesn't solve the problem. Any idea?

[image]

```css
.menu {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.pat:hover {
  color: #EC008C;
}

.l {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.sub-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu .pat:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li class="pat">Patenti
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="l"><a href="patentea.html">Patente A</a></li>
      <li class="l"><a href="patenteb.html">Patente B</a></li>
      <li class="l"><a href="patsup.html">Patenti superiori</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>News</li>
  <li><a href="contatti.html">Contatti</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried...

Comment: Post your HTML/CSS codes

Comment: HTML: https://ibb.co/mkZ9u8 CSS: https://ibb.co/jGg5Z8

Comment: Can you paste them as text on your post? Or maybe go and create a codepen.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajzXyN on codepen it looks different. Is this how you want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `visibility: hidden;` and `visibility: visible;` on `hover` for submenus, it's better to use `display: none` and `display: block`, and use `position: absolute` on the submenu and `position: relative` on its parent menu entry.

The reason `display: none` doesn't take any space (and `position: absolute` will prevent the visible submenu to change the design of the main menu entries), whereas `visibility: hidden;` reserves the space for the hidden element and just makes it invisible, which makes it impossible to properly position it independently of objects which it should cover when visible.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `position: relative` to `.menu`. It will create a stacking context causing it to appear above body text.

Here is a [modified pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xJbBEP?editors=1100). I have rewritten all rules but only the last one is important.